# Take a variable outside a loop to work with it

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have made a loop which gives me a lot of file paths (in a list). These file paths are assigned to a variable inside the loop named `all_file_paths`.

Now I'm planning to do a lot of code with that variable so to keep things properly I want to take that variable outside the loop and work further with it. Because if I keep working inside that loop, the loop will get to big and things might get confusing. But as you might already know, as soon as I take the variable outside the loop I'm not working anymore with the same content assigned to that variable. I just get an empty list :(

Is their a proper way to take variables outside a loop and work with them as if they where inside the loop?

This is my code example, I would like to know if theirs a trick for it so I can do the same for much bigger scripts. Thx.

```
source = r'c:\data\JS\Desktop\MyFolder'

for subdir in os.listdir(source):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(source, subdir)
#    print(subdir_path)
    
    all_file_paths = [os.path.join(subdir_path, file) for file in os.listdir(subdir_path)]
    all_file_paths = [p for p in all_file_paths if os.path.isfile(p)]
    print(all_file_paths) #<----- when I print this, I get what I need.
    
print(all_file_paths) #<-----when I print this I get an empty list.
```

Comment: you should get the same values in variable even outside loop. The only problem can be if you run `for`-loop inside function and try to use variable outside function because inside function it will create local variable which has nothing to do with external variable. And you should use `return all_file_paths` in function and run `all_file_paths = function()` - so problem would has nothing to do with `for`-loop but with `function`

Comment: `all_file_paths` will have a *different value* for each iteration of the loop.  If you examine it after the loop, it will have whatever value it had during the final iteration of the loop; all the previous values are gone.  You either need to do everything you need to do with this variable inside the loop, or append it to a list so that you have all of the values available after the loop.

Comment: @furas. So you are saying I have to make a function of it? But the same problem will still exist. Because I cant use the variable outside a function....

Comment: @jasonharper append it inside or outside a loop?

Comment: I say you may have problem only if you run loop inside function - without funciton it should gives correct values. And we can't recreate this problem because it works correctly on our computers. OR maybe it is only problem with your system or with Python which you use.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment, if you're asking that question.  Inside the loop is the only place where all of the various values assigned to `all_file_paths` exist.  Outside the loop, only one of those values still exist.

Comment: I see what @jasonharper says - variable can keep only values from last loop and if in last loop it creates empty list then outside for-loop you get empty list. You should rather create list before `for`-loop, `append()` to this list inside `for`-loop and then you will have all values after `for`-loop.

Comment: Okay. Thank you I will try to make a list before for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `all_file_paths` can keep only values from last loop and if in last loop it creates empty list then after `for`-loop you will have only empty list.

You should create list before `for`-loop. And inside `for`-loop you should `append()` or `extend()` this list.

```
source = r'c:\data\JS\Desktop\MyFolder'

# -- before --

all_file_paths = []

# -- inside --

for subdir in os.listdir(source):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(source, subdir)
    
    results = [os.path.join(subdir_path, file) for file in os.listdir(subdir_path)]
    results = [p for p in results if os.path.isfile(p)]
    print('(partial) results:', results)

    all_file_paths.extend(results) # add to list

# --- after ---
    
print('(all) results:', all_file_paths)
```

Comment: that worked for me. Thanks, but It gets really difficult coding with just lists after the loop.

Comment: what so difficult ? it is natural method. If you try to convert your list comprehensions to normal `for`-loop then you get something similar. And if you don't want to use after loop then use partial `results` inside `for`-loop